# if condition in bugzilla template file to check if the bug is cloned bug

Tags: perl, templates, toolkit, bugzilla

how can i write an if condition in bugzilla template file to check if the bug is cloned bug

I wrote the code

```
[% IF cloned_bug_id eq [% bug.bug_id %] ]
  <a href="mailto:[% report_name %]">HIIIIIIIIIIII</a>
[% END %]
```

but it is showing error:

> URL:http://stagingbugzilla.cpiv.com/html/centralbugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=3743085
>   file error - parse error - bug/edit.html.tmpl line 1145: unexpected token (eq) [% IF  cloned_bug_id eq [% bug.bug_id %]

Comment: Its very urgent. Please reply someone

Comment: It is very urgent. Can anybody please reply

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is template toolkit, there is no reason to nest code blocks ( `[% %]` ). Also, `eq` is not used for comparison. From the template toolkit documentation:

> The following conditional and boolean operators may be used:

```
== != < <= > >= && || ! and or not
```

Something like this should work:

```
[% IF cloned_bug_id == bug.bug_id %]
   <a href="mailto:[% report_name %]">HIIIIIIIIIIII</a>
[% END %]
```